# Maven Invoker plugin log to console (System.out)?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

Is it somehow possible to configure [Maven Invoker Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/) to log to the System.out instead of build.log file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maven-invoker-plugin has two parameters [noLog](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#noLog) or [streamLog](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#streamLogs) you should check if one of them would fulfill your requirement. I would assume the streamLog should be right direction.

Comment: Indeed, it's `streamLogs` that I was after :))

Answer (score 0):

No.  They create the file logger and used it extensively:

```
private FileLogger setupLogger( File basedir )
    throws MojoExecutionException
{
    FileLogger logger = null;

    if ( !noLog )
    {
        File outputLog = new File( basedir, "build.log" );
        try
        {
            if ( streamLogs )
            {
                logger = new FileLogger( outputLog, getLog() );
            }
            else
            {
                logger = new FileLogger( outputLog );
            }

            getLog().debug( "build log initialized in: " + outputLog );
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            throw new MojoExecutionException( "Error initializing build logfile in: " + outputLog, e );
        }
    }

    return logger;
}
```

Comment: The [streamLogs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#streamLogs) seemed to be exactly what the op is looking for and which can be followed within the code.